# Why traits::access cannot be compiled (c++)?

Tags: c++, boost, type-traits, boost-geometry

I am now learning how to use [boost::geometry](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/index.html) library, and I am following the tutorial, where type traits are introduced to make the codes more generic. For example, the `distance` function below is regarded as genetic by using traits:

```
struct mypoint
{
    double x, y;
};

template <typename P1, typename P2>
double distance(P1 const& a, P2 const& b)
{
    double dx = get<0>(a) - get<0>(b);
    double dy = get<1>(a) - get<1>(b);
    return std::sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
}

template <typename P1, typename P2>
double distance(P1 const& a, P2 const& b)
{
    double dx = get<0>(a) - get<0>(b);
    double dy = get<1>(a) - get<1>(b);
    return std::sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
}

namespace traits
{
    template <>
    struct access<mypoint, 0>
    {
        static double get(mypoint const& p)
        {
            return p.x;
        }
    };

    template <>
    struct access<mypoint, 1>
    {
        static double get(mypoint const& p)
        {
            return p.y;
        }
    };

}
```

However, when I compile the codes, the following compilation errors happen:

```
Error   3   error C2913: explicit specialization; 'traits::access' is not a specialization of a class template
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: The term is "generic", not "genetic" :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have specialized `traits::access` without giving a generic definition, so add:

```
namespace traits
{
    template <typename, int>
        struct access;
    /* ... */
}
```